# Calculate "as the crow flies" distance php

Tags: php, google-maps

I am currently calculating the driving distance between two points on one of my wordpress websites inside of a function. I accomplish this using the google distance matrix by calling

```
wp_remote_get(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".
    urlencode($origin).
    "&destinations=".
    urlencode($destination).
    "&sensor=false&units=imperial"
)
```

and then inserting the origins and destinations users have entered via a form into the url. Is it possible to use a similar approach to calculating an "as the crow flies" distance or do I have to rework my function?

Comment: that you can do without google maps. Search for the formula that gets you the physical shortest distance between two points on the globe.

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distance between 2 points: (lat1,lon1) to (lat2,lon2)

```
distance = acos(
     cos(lat1 * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lon1 * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lat2 * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lon2 * (PI()/180))
     +
     cos(lat1 * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lon1 * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lat2 * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lon2 * (PI()/180))
     +
     sin(lat1 * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lat2 * (PI()/180))
    ) * 3959
```

---

3959 is the Earth radius in Miles. Replace this value with
radius in KM, (or any other unit), to get results on the same unit.

You can verify your implementation by comparing to this [**worked example**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Worked_example):