# Google Maps Custom Markers in an Area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate “as the crow flies” distance php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845152/calculate-as-the-crow-flies-distance-php)

I am trying to develop a **GoogleMaps** page where I can get the user location and show custom marker points from an **XML** file that fells within the calculated area around the user.

To make things more clear :

1. I have a radius parameter from **WebConfig** file, say 5000 (in meters)
2. I've found the user location on map,
3. Using the **xml** list that I own (xml has the Lat-Long values of
   each store) I want to put **custom markers** on map which fell within
   the 5 km^2 *area range* with the **user's location as center**.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

How do I calculate a point's Lat & Long values by only passing user's location coordinates and a distance parameter (say 5000 in my case)?

Edit :

> My XML doc is kinda huge including whitegoods stores all around the
>   country. My main problem is to filter these rows of data (long,latt)
>   using user's current location.
>
> ```
> I need something like:
> func distanceCale(int long, int latt, int radius)
> to return me some values that can help me filter my XML data.
>
> I guess my question was not clear enough at the firs place. :)
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [**Haversine formula**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). This formula has been used in a  [**Demo**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmapXML.php) from an XML file showing markers within a given radius.

For your application the javascript  code is used to generate markers from XML file.

```
function deg2rad(degrees){
radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
//document.write(radians);
return radians;

}
function Haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  deltaLat = lat2 - lat1 ;
  deltaLon = lon2 - lon1 ;
  earthRadius = 3959; // in miles 6371 in meters.
  alpha    = deltaLat/2;
  beta     = deltaLon/2;
  a        = Math.sin(deg2rad(alpha)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(alpha)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(beta)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(beta)) ;
  c        = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  distance =  earthRadius * c;
  return distance.toFixed(2);
}
```

The  Haversine function is used when parsing XML

```
var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var lat = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat"));
         var lng = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              lat,
              lng);
        var  distance = Haversine(center.lat(),center.lng(),lat,lng);
        if(distance<=radius) {    
         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, distance);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
         }
```

Comment: My XML doc is kinda huge including whitegoods stores all around the country. My main problem is to filter these rows of data (long,latt) using user's current location.

I need something like:
func distanceCale(int long, int latt, int radius)
to return me some values that can help me filter my XML data.

I guess my question was not clear enough.

Comment: The haversine formula allows you to do that lat1, lon1 are your user's position.  iterate through your xml, using each point as lat2, lon2.  This gives you the distance, if it is less than the radius, display it on the map, if greater than the radius, don't display it.  You might be better off using a spatially enabled database or FusionTables to store your data.

Comment: @ouzmpasa see edited answer with new link to map with markers from XML file

Comment: @davidstrachan Thank you for editing your answer and making it more clear. I am kinda emberrased after realizing your first answer was also useful :)

For those who are looking for a close solution, I've found some working example : http://www.pjtecnologia.com.br/maps/exemplos/check-lat-lng-is-inside-a-circle.html